# SQL Server database shared among different projects

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have a project that stores data in its local `.mdf` database file. And the second one which is web application that presents graphically data from that `.mdf` database. But trying to get data with linq from my web app I got:

> "Unable to open the physical file databse.mdf.
>   Operating system error 32: "32 (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".
>   A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Use a database server like SQL Express or real SQL Server. You can't share a database using file level access.

Comment: SQL **Server** is a **server-based** system and should be used as such - stop fiddling around with "free-floating" `.mdf` files already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple users (or programs) cannot attach directly to the `.mdf`.

You need to run SQL Server and connect to the server (not file) for concurrency.

The connection string will have the name of the SQL Server (not a path to the `.mdf` file)

```
Data Source=MSSQL1;Database=AdventureWorks;
```